# How to make Aurelia run under local host setup in local IIS

Tags: localhost, aurelia

I am new to Aurelia world, and I have static aurelia running (C:\Projects\Aurelia) and it is creating "dist" folder when I run command "au build" and it is using default port 8080. Now I have created Web API project with VS 2017 and I want to use same port to avoid CORS issues, so created sub application as (localhost:8080/WebApi). But "au build" is not happy with it as it says "Permission denied" as I am using same port to setup through IIS.

I search through google and did not find any help that I am looking for.
Can anyone help me how to achieve this?

Comment: what I found to be the best approach is to allow cors for DEV only. so I run `au run` on port 8080 and my api on a different port. but if you want to stay with your setup - you can create a folder inside your api (call it `pages`) - and move the aurelia project there - then browse your pages from the api port. you'll just need to ajust the base url in webpack config.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to configure a virtual directory in IIS (i.e. alias in Apache) to point to the `/dist` folder with your Aurelia application, e.g. with `ui` context, next to another `WebApi`.

I usually have something like `http://localhost/ui` for aurelia app and `http://localhost/api` for a backend API allowing Aurelia components to perform ajax calls to API without CORS on local httpd server instead of running on local nodejs on port 8080.

Note that you can run `au build --watch` instead of `au run` in order to build on every change in source dir, and don't need nodejs instance anymore.